# Printing checks in .Net from blank stock (Not pre-printed checks)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, printing

I would like to take blank secure stock paper and convert it in to a check.

I know you can get magnetic toner and print MICR.

The question is
 What is  the actual font to use or should i get a package and send the data to it to print the check?

Has anybody done it successfully without having to resort to pre-printed checks.

etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the potential cost of getting this wrong, my first approach would be to buy something in that could do this.

You get something that should work straight away rather than having to develop it and, more importantly, support for when it goes wrong.

Disclaimer - I haven't done any research on this to find out what packages (if any) are out there.

Answer (score 0):

This company sells fonts, paper and MICR fonts. http://www.micrfonts.com/about-micr.htm